# How to transfer only several apps data from old iPhone to new iPhone?

Tags: iphone, finder, backup

I just buy new iPhone. I want to transfer *only* Whatsapp chat history, and none of all the other apps. I want to start with clean slate. I don't want to going through each app to delete them one by one on the new iPhone. But I still need all the Whatsapp chat history. How can I do that using  Finder? I presume I have to use the backup on Finder to backup just the selected app (Whatsapp), and then use the backup to restore on the new iPhone. But how do I do that (backup just the selected app)? I don't see any selection on the Finder iPhone management to do that. Only "Back Up Now" button.